# XMLGregorianCalendar date format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS'

Tags: java, xml, date

```
String formatA ="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
String formatB = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS";
try {
    XMLGregorianCalendar gregFmt = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(new SimpleDateFormat(formatB).format(new Date()));
    System.out.println(gregFmt);
} catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
};
```

I am trying to formate XMLGregorianCalendar date .
The above code formats well for format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"`

But for  formatB `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS`    it throws error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Do advice on how to fix it.  Thank you so much!

log

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 23/08/2017 16:13:04.140
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parseAndSetYear(XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java:2887)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parse(XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java:2773)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.<init>(XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java:435)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl.newXMLGregorianCalendar(DatatypeFactoryImpl.java:536)
at test.test.main(test.java:19)
```

line19 is line 4 , in the above code 'XMLGregorianCalendar gregFmt...'

Comment: what part of your huge line is throwing this exception?

Comment: It's this part of the code 'newXMLGregorianCalendar' that can't take dates of format  dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS              ihave added in the log to above

Comment: try to add timezone in date format.
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Answer (score 4):

The format that `newXMLGregorianCalendar(string)` accept is described in [the XML specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime-lexical-representation) and is different from the `formatB` you are trying to use.

Comment: The link you seem to have obtained from the javadoc is linking to the wrong anchor. The lexical representation is specified under https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime-lexical-representation.

Comment: Indeed I got it from the javadoc, indeed it was the wrong anchor. Changed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

- Date-time objects do not have a “format”. They parse & generate `String` objects representing textually their value.
- Use the modern *java.time* that replaced terrible old classes `Date` & `XMLGregorianCalendar` classes.

Example:

```
myXMLGregorianCalendar   // If you must use this class… but try to avoid. Use *java.time* classes instead.
.toGregorianCalendar()   // Converting from `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar` to `java.util.GregorianCalendar`.
.toZonedDateTime()       // Converting from `java.util.GregorianCalendar` to `java.time.ZonedDateTime`, from legacy class to modern class.
.format(                 // Generate a `String` representing the moment stored in our `ZonedDateTime` object.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss.SSS" )  // Define a formatting pattern as you desire. Or better, automatically localize by calling `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…` methods.
)                        // Returns a `String` object, distinct from our `ZonedDateTime` object.
```

> 07/07/2018 15:20:14.372

## Date-time objects do not have a format

Do not conflate date-time objects with the strings they generate to represent their value. Date-time values, including the classes discussed below, are not a `String`, do not use text as their internal value, and do not have a “format”. All of them can generate, and parse, strings to represent their date-time value.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as [`XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html).

The use of  `java.util.Date` should be replaced with `java.time.Instant`. Both represent a moment in UTC. `Instant` uses a finer resolution of nanoseconds rather than milliseconds.

You can easily convert between the modern and legacy classes. Notice the new conversion methods added to the old classes, in this case [`java.util.GregorianCalendar::toZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#toZonedDateTime()).

First convert from [`javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html) to [`java.util.GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html).

```
GregorianCalendar gc = myXMLGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar() ;
```

Now get out of these legacy classes, and into java.time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

All three types so far, the `XMLGregorianCalendar`, the `GregorianCalendar`, and the `ZonedDateTime` all represent the same moment, a date with time-of-day and an assigned time zone.

With a `ZonedDateTime` in hand, you can generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format extended to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;  // Generate string in standard ISO 8601 format extended by appending the name of time zone in square brackets.
```

> 2018-07-07T15:20:14.372-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

You can generate strings in other formats using `DateTimeFormatter` class. For the formatting pattern listed second in your question, define a matching `DateTimeFormatter` object.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss.SSS" ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

> 07/07/2018 15:20:14.372

The first formatting pattern listed in your Question has a `Z` on the end, which means UTC and is pronounced “Zulu”. To adjust our `ZonedDateTime` to UTC, simply extract a `Instant` object. An `Instant` is always in UTC by definition.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Extract an `Instant` object, always in UTC.
```

Generate a String in the pattern shown first in the Question.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;  // Generate string in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2018-07-07T22:20:14.372Z

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).